# How do I get the average of every 10 numbers in list in python

Tags: python

```
list []
list contains [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

How do I get the average of every 10 numbers from list?

Comment: Explain what your code is supposed to do. What are the inputs and expected outputs. What is happening in your code now that leads you to believe that it is not working. Ultimately, please read how to put together a better [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: By `average of every 10 numbers` you mean `average of 1-10`, then `11-20 ` and so on?

Comment: Every 10 numbers combination produces 30 milions averages!

Comment: yes Moinuddin. I could do average = sum(list[0:10])/10 but that's not very efficient for bigger list than this one.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the sample code. Iterate over your list of numbers for every `step` i.e. `10` in your case. Calculate the `average` of the elements between the step.

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
>>> step = 10
>>> for i, _ in enumerate(my_list[::step]):
...     sub_list = my_list[i*10:] if (i+1)*10 > len(my_list) else my_list[i*10:(i+1)*10]  # Condition if the len(my_list) % step != 0
...     print sum(sub_list)/float(len(sub_list))  # Dividing by float' to get decimal value as average (Not needed in Python 3)
... 
5.5
15.5
25.5
```

Comment: AWESOME !! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The averages can be computed without creating sublists:

```
testdata = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
        19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30] 

LEN = 10

def avg(data):
    datasum = cnt = 0 
    for num in data:
        datasum += num
        cnt += 1
        if cnt == LEN: 
            yield datasum / LEN
            datasum = cnt = 0 
    if cnt: 
        yield datasum / cnt

print(list(avg(testdata)))
# [5.5, 15.5, 25.5]
```

---

An alternative implementation with sublists:

```
def avg(data):
    for i in range((len(data) + LEN - 1) // LEN):
        sublist = data[i*LEN:(i+1)*LEN]
        yield sum(sublist) / len(sublist)
```

Note: this is Python3 code where int/int is float. In Python2 int/int is int.