# Writing a function that calculates the average value of 5 parameters from user input

Tags: python-3.x, string, integer, average

I need to build a code that will give the average sum of 5 user input parameters. I have to add all 5 parameters, and then divide the addition by 5. I also have to make sure the function uses the return command to return the average as the value for the function. Since I am a beginner I can't use advanced code. Been stuck for days.

I have tried converting the string into an int

I have tried converting a list to a string to an int

I have tried making multiple variables.

```
from statistics import mean

a = input("Enter 1st number:")
b = input("Enter 2nd number:")
c = input("Enter 3rd number:")
d = input("Enter 4th number:")
e = input("Enter 5th number:")
inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
input1 = int(inputs)
mean(inputs)


import math

a = input("Enter 1st number:")
b = input("Enter 2nd number:")
c = input("Enter 3rd number:")
d = input("Enter 4th number:")
e = input("Enter 5th number:")
inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
avg_mean = "5"
totals = int(inputs) / avg_mean
```

I expect to get all 5 user input numbers and divide it by 5 to get the average sum.

Comment: You should try to implement this yourself. This is fairly basic as far as assignments go. I would suggest learning the basics of python first - look for tutorials online, or ask your teacher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the average of every 10 numbers in list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814034/how-do-i-get-the-average-of-every-10-numbers-in-list-in-python)

Comment: Yeah I thought the same thing it would be fairly easy, I read both books I have, this was the first assignment I was hung up on.

Comment: Saw that link as well, this was definitely my last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues, I will point a few out for you:

```
from statistics import mean

a = input("Enter 1st number:")
b = input("Enter 2nd number:")
c = input("Enter 3rd number:")
d = input("Enter 4th number:")
e = input("Enter 5th number:")
```

Up to this point you are OK, you could store these inputs better and use a loop instead of copy pasting 5 times but this will still give you what you want

```
inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

The above line is not doing what I imagine you want.  If you want to put your 5 values into a list you need to use the variables `a,b,c,d,e` instead of the characters `'a','b','c','d','e'`

```
inputs = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

Next up, `int()` does not work on lists as a whole, you need to pass 1 string at a time.  here's a simple way to do this:

```
for i in range(5): 
    inputs[i] = int(inputs[i])
```

Then, mean will work as you want with the integer `inputs` list

```
mean(inputs)
```

Finally, you mention wanting to turn this into a function, once everything is working, turning it into a function with a `return` value is quite easy.  I'll leave that up to your research

Comment: Awesome feedback! I did have a feeling my original list was incorrect, I started with [a, b, c, d, e] then [a + b + c + d + e]/5... This was the first time I've been so lost, thought it would be pretty simple, going to play around with it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### A pythonic implementation

- Create `input` directly into a list and repeat with `range`

  - There's no need to create a separate object for each input
  - There's no need to then load those 5 objects into another object
- Convert `input` to `int` immediately with `int(input())`
- [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) works on the entire list
- `[x for x in range(5)]` is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- `f'Input {x} values'` is an [f-String](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)
- The function accepts a parameter for how many inputs.  The default is `5`, but that isn't used if you pass some other number when the function is called.

```py
from statistics import mean

def mean_of_inputs(number_of_inputs: int=5) -> float:
    return mean([int(input(f'Please input {x + 1} of {number_of_inputs} numbers: ')) for x in range(number_of_inputs)])

# Use the function
mean_of_inputs(6)

Please input 1 of 6 numbers:  10
Please input 2 of 6 numbers:  20
Please input 3 of 6 numbers:  30
Please input 4 of 6 numbers:  40
Please input 5 of 6 numbers:  50
Please input 6 of 6 numbers:  60
35
```

### Alternative 1:

- No `list comprehension`
- No imported modules
- Stores all the inputs in `numbers` and uses the built-in function, `sum`

```py
def mean_of_inputs(number_of_inputs: int=5) -> float:

    numbers = list()
    for x in range(number_of_inputs):
        numbers.append(int(input(f'Please input {x + 1} of {number_of_inputs} numbers: ')))

    return sum(numbers) / number_of_inputs
```

#### Call the function:

```py
mean_of_inputs()

Please input 1 of 5 numbers:  2
Please input 2 of 5 numbers:  4
Please input 3 of 5 numbers:  6
Please input 4 of 5 numbers:  8
Please input 5 of 5 numbers:  10
6.0
```

### Alternative 2:

- Don't store the inputs, just add them to a running total

```py
def mean_of_inputs(number_of_inputs: int=5) -> float:

    sum_of_inputs = 0
    for x in range(number_of_inputs):
        sum_of_inputs += int(input(f'Please input {x + 1} of {number_of_inputs} numbers: '))

    return sum_of_inputs / number_of_inputs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from statistics import mean

a = input("Enter 1st number:")
b = input("Enter 2nd number:")
c = input("Enter 3rd number:")
d = input("Enter 4th number:")
e = input("Enter 5th number:")

m = mean(map(int, [a,b,c,d,e]))
```